# ScheduledExecutorService task will be executed by multi-thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, scheduledexecutorservice

This makes me really curious.There is a button which sends a simple post request by ajax on a jsp page,and I use a RESTFUL method to handle this request,but that method will be executed twice or three times.This will only happen on CentOS 7.3,on my laptop I use windows10, multi-thread will not happen.I have searched on Google but nothing helpful 
 has been found.Here are the codes:

> asset.jsp:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="allDoMi">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down">allDoMi</i>
</button>
$("button[title='allDoMi']").click(function () {
    var dataparam = "version=1";
    if (!confirm('confirm all DoMi？'))
        return;
    //ajax request
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: serviceurl.baseurl + "/asset/doMiAction",
        data: dataparam,
        beforeSend: function () {
             //do nothing
        },
        error: function () {
             //do nothing
        },
        success: function (info) {
             //do nothing    
        }
    });
});
```

> Asset.java

```
@Service
@Path("/asset")
public class AssetRest {
    @Path("/doMiAction")
    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
                                 MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public RestfulResult doMiAction(@FormParam("version") String 
          version) {
          logger.info("doMiAction method began....");
          //package data for duMiSyncDtos,here only for test
          List<DuMiSyncDto> duMiSyncDtos =new List<>();
          //this url is for http simulation using HttpURLConnection
          final String dumiUrl = "http://someip/someurl";
          final Map<String, List<DuMiSyncDto>> map; 
          //only continue when list is not empty
          if (!duMiSyncDtos.isEmpty()) {
             //this method used for sync data in a certain order
             map = groupList(duMiSyncDtos);
             SortedSet<String> ss = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());
             final Iterator<String> iter = ss.iterator();
             final ScheduledExecutorService ticker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
             logger.info("NEW A SINGLETHREADSCHEDULEDEXECUTOR");
             //retrieve data from a .property file,I set it 20000,therefore the job will be executed in every 20 seconds
             final int DELAY = NumberUtils.toInt(WebUtils.getConfigValue("dumi.delay"));
             ticker.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
             private int count;
             public void run() {
                logger.info("BEGIN RUN METHOD:"+System.identityHashCode(AssetRest.this));
                if(iter.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        List<DuMiSyncDto> value = map.get(iter.next());
                        //this method used for simulating a httprequest using HttpURLConnection to invoke a remote service to get the result info which forms in a JSON string format
                        String resultmsg = getDuMiReturnMessage(dumiUrl,value);
                        if(resultmsg!=null && !resultmsg.contains("\"code\":\"0000\"")) {
                            logger.info("Return code is "+resultmsg+",the sync work will be terminated.");
                            ticker.shutdown();
                            return;
                        }
                        //this method used for showing some useful infomation on the console using log4j
                        showSyncInfomation(value);
                        //this method used for count how many items have been synchronized successfully
                        int currentcount = getSyncCount(resultmsg);
                        count += currentcount ;
                        logger.info("current sync  data:"+currentcount+"，summing data"+count+"");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("method[doMiAction]...executing schedule:",e);
                    }
                } else {
                    ticker.shutdown();
                }
            }
        }, 0, DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

After I click the button,all the log info will be shown on Putty console for two or three times,yet I have clicked that button for only ONCE!I have tested for several times,it will happen,but in windows on my laptop,this will not happen at all.Here is a detail might be help:previously the implementation for timed execution is not like this,it has been written like :

```
for(DuMiSyncDto dto:duMiSyncDtoList){
    //do the business code
    Thread.sleep(20000);
}
```

Because there is database synchronization from the remote service,I need to control the interval time not too soon between every two operations:execute in every 20 seconds and 100 data at a time.In this situation,the multi-thread problem occurs,I thought it may be the for loop which aroused so I change the way using a JDK API instead but issues were still there.So WHY all of these?

---------------------------first edit------------------------------------------

```
private int getSyncCount(String resultmsg) {
    int count = 0;
    JSONObject obj = JSONObject.fromObject(resultmsg);
    String message = obj.getString("message");
    if(!WebUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        String[] arr = message.split(" ");
        if(arr!=null && arr.length>1) {
            count += Integer.parseInt(arr[1].trim());
        }
    }
    logger.info("currentThreadName:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return count;
}
```

Notice in this method,I log the current thread name,and it shows :

```
...     
currentThreadName:pool-1-thread-1
currentThreadName:pool-2-thread-1
currentThreadName:pool-3-thread-1
...
```

when there are 3 threads.

Comment: Is the log statement "doMiAction method began...." appearing more than once even when you click the button once? If yes, then the issue might be elsewhere rather than code. If not, can you tell on one click what all log statements are appearing on console?

Comment: Yes,all the info in logger.info method will appear more than once,it seems somebody else clicks that button ,but none in fact,and  I only click it once indeed.Please see my first edit for more details.

Comment: Can you try to inspect the number of calls from browser when you try the click? Also, can you try a curl request with post from the machine and see if multiple requests are being made. Just to eliminate there is no issue with the browser or mouse :)

Comment: Same environment at my laptop with Windows10,nothing weird happened.

Comment: I agree. But again its to check whether issue is with the code or the environment. If you run the curl command from with in that CentOS box and it results in just one request, then maybe the issue is somewhere in the gateway or proxy in middle.

Comment: Seems like it is having clicking issue from frontend! Some kind of display/mouse click response issue!

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with code itself??